# wordpress edit lock

Tags: php, wordpress, locking

I have a custom post type (product) that have a meta field that 
hold's inventory quantity.

Once an order is made im updating the quantity

`$qty=get_post_meta($post->ID,'stock',true);

$qty--;

Update_post_meta($post->ID,'stock',$qty);`

The thing is im afraid that multiple and simultanious calls for this update
Might cause the data to be incorrect If a call will be made while another call is in process...

Is there a way to lock that piece of code and make sure it wont be fired
Simultaniously or am i exadurating in my concerns ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well generally there shouldnt be a concern, my issue is why are you getting the quantity and then using it to subtract it and update it again, when everything can be done in one step. I am assuming those 2 methods are making some call to a database. In MYsql you can do something like

```
UPDATE yourtable SET quantity = quantity-1 WHERE id = ....
```

That way the deduction happens in your database and you are saving one query...

Comment: Well i think that might solve it , because mysql will lock that field for editing ... thx

Comment: Thats true, but keep in mind you will have to be experience tremendous amounts of concurrency before the first scenario really becomes an issue and if you are, make sure you are using transactions for your writing queries...

Comment: can you asses what amount of concurrency can make this process fail ? (i know it is a matter of hardware and other stuff but lets say for an intermediate system and a rough number will be enough :-) )

Comment: I am not really sure, but think about it, in order for that to happen you will have to have 2 people ordering at exactly the same milisecond...what is the chance to have a 1000 orders in the same second so that could even become an issue ? And even if it is usually ecommerce applications have a backend task to syncronize quantities with the store, especially if you are processing 1000s of orders a second, never mind if you have such a volume i wouldnt even go with PHP for its lack of good support for transactions...